# Active Websocket Connection Limit Reached:

Tags: websocket, weblogic12c, apache2.4

I am using weblogic proxy plugin (12c) for Apache (v2.4). Apache logs is giving the following error after some time:

```
[Mon Jun 27 13:01:09.570646 2016] [weblogic:error] [pid 18224] [client 192.135.176.51:60667] ap_proxy: trying GET /websocket/hcsnotifications/jSocket at backend host ; got exception 'NO_RESOURCES: [os error=115,  line 2859 of ApacheProxy.cpp]: Active Websocket Connection Limit Reached'; state: preparing request headers (wrote? N read? N); not failing over
[Mon Jun 27 13:01:09.570700 2016] [weblogic:error] [pid 18224] [client 192.135.176.51:60667] <18224146704686919> request [/websocket/hcsnotifications/jSocket] did NOT process successfully..................
[Mon Jun 27 13:01:09.769993 2016] [weblogic:error] [pid 23558] [client 192.135.176.11:28072] Active Websocket Connection Limit Reached: 192
[Mon Jun 27 13:01:09.770063 2016] [weblogic:error] [pid 23558] [client 192.135.176.11:28072] <23558146704686921> *******Exception type [NO_RESOURCES] (Active Websocket Connection Limit Reached) raised at line 2859 of ApacheProxy.cpp
```

Following is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 295
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
WLMaxWebSocketClients 1024

# prefork MPM
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers      25
MinSpareServers   50
MaxSpareServers   200
ServerLimit      2048
MaxClients       2048
MaxRequestsPerChild  2000
#WLMaxWebSocketClients 1024
</IfModule>
```

So as per above config I have set WebSocket connection limit to 1024, but it reached the limit at 30-40 connections.

Comment: An example of how to config the  parameters http://www.ateam-oracle.com/ohs-tuning-parameters-for-oam/